# parsing and get value from large file php

Tags: php, file-get-contents, large-files

I have a problem with the use of very large files. I tried to make a solution by splitting the files into several parts. but the problem is still there because it's a large file.
illustrations like this :

```
A = 1GB file;
I broke into
file A_1 = 200MB, file A_2 = 200MB, and so on.
```

My logic is , if I use one file (A), then I do :

```
for ( ... )
{
    $data = file_get_contents("data/A.vcf");

//code that is very complex (including parsing the data) related to the contents of the data and I will often use file_get_contents due to looping
}
```

then I change my logic into several parts by using the value / position of the file, ie :

```
for ( ... )
{
   switch($position)
   {
      case(($position >= 0) && ($position < 5000000)):
      $data = file_get_contents("data/A_1.vcf");
      break;

      case(($position >= 5000000) && ($position < 10000000)):
      $data = file_get_contents("data/A_2.vcf");
      break;

      case(($position >= 10000000) && ($position < 20000000)):
      $data = file_get_contents("data/A_3.vcf");
      break;

      case(($position >= 20000000) && ($position < 30000000)):
      $data = file_get_contents("data/A_4.vcf");
      break;
     ...
   }
   //code that is very complex ( including parsing the data ) related to the contents of the data and I will often use file_get_contents due to looping
}
```

but the problem still remains, because of large data. I've tried to delete most of the data into 200KB, and solutions resolved. but that's not what I want, because the data is incomplete.
is there any other solution to solve this problem ? whether due to the use of file_get_contents which cause so it can not? is there any other way to retrieve the value of a very large file?

> [UPDATE]

```
<?php
            /*
            I take random data from multiple large files to try
            50001374    rs389045667 T   C
            10000685    rs123308931 A   C
            39769437    rs393441165 C   T
            26907032    rs393470108 C   T
            50001195    rs122244329 G   T
            */

            $posi = array(50001374,10000685,39769437, 26907032, 50001195);
            $id = array(".",".",".",".",".");
            $ref = array("T","A","C","C","G");
            $alt = array("C","C","T","T","T");

            for($i=0; $i<5; $i++)
            {
                switch($posi[$i])
                {
                    case (($posi[$i] >= 0 ) && ($posi[$i] < 5000000 )):
                    $data = file_get_contents("data/ncbi/5.vcf");
                    break;

                    case (($posi[$i] >= 5000000 ) && ($posi[$i] < 10000000 )):
                    $data = file_get_contents("data/ncbi/10.vcf");
                    break;

                    case (($posi[$i] >= 10000000 ) && ($posi[$i] < 20000000 )):
                    $data = file_get_contents("data/ncbi/20.vcf");
                    break;

                    case (($posi[$i] >= 20000000 ) && ($posi[$i] < 30000000 )):
                    $data = file_get_contents("data/ncbi/30.vcf");
                    break;

                    case (($posi[$i][2] >= 30000000 ) && ($posi[$i] < 40000000 )):
                    $data = file_get_contents("data/ncbi/40.vcf");
                    break;

                    case (($posi[$i] >= 40000000 ) && ($posi[$i] < 50000000 )):
                    $data = file_get_contents("data/ncbi/50.vcf");
                    break;

                    case ($posi[$i] >= 50000000 ):
                    $data = file_get_contents("data/ncbi/60.vcf");
                    break;
                }
            $data = explode("\n", $data);

            $data2=array();
            foreach ($data2 as $dat)
            {
                $data2[] = explode("\t", $dat);  
            }

            for($j = 0 ; $j < count($data2); $j++)
            {
                if($data2[$j][1] == $posi[$i] && $data2[$j][3] == $ref[$i] && $data2[$j][4] == $alt[$i])
                {
                    echo '<pre>';
                    print_r($posi[$i]. "\n");
                    print_r($id[$i]. "\n");
                    print_r($ref[$i]. "\n");
                    print_r($alt[$i]. "\n");
                    echo '</pre>';
                    break;
                }

            }
}
?>
```

explanation: 
in this case, the position data is already sorted. in the code, I want it when `"if($data2[$j][1] == $posi[$i] && $data2[$j][3] == $ref[$i] && $data2[$j][4] == $alt[$i])"` is true, then the file was released and out of the loop `"for $j"`. then up to the beginning of the loop `(for $i)`, and perform file selection (switch), and `"if($data2[$j][1] == $posi[$i] && $data2[$j][3] == $ref[$i] && $data2[$j][4] == $alt[$i])"`, and so on.
So, i dont read all file, I just read the file until the position is found.

but I do not know how to free up the file. if I do the above code always fails on files that are too large.

Comment: Do you have to have all the data at once? Can you read it line by line instead, freeing older lines from memory as you go?

Comment: I actually like it wanted. I have edited my post clearer. Can you help me?

Comment: Seems like there is a code error. You are doing: `$data2=array();` Then looping based on `$data2` which will always be empty.

Comment: no, $data2 I use to separate "\t". i want to ask, how to free up the file? So, i dont read all file, I just read the file until the position is found.

Comment: See the answer I added. You use `fgets` to read line by line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do reading line by line, also you can do the same with just 1 file, even if it is 1 GB (will just take longer):

```
<?php
/*
I take random data from multiple large files to try
50001374    rs389045667 T   C
10000685    rs123308931 A   C
39769437    rs393441165 C   T
26907032    rs393470108 C   T
50001195    rs122244329 G   T
*/

$posi = array(50001374,10000685,39769437, 26907032, 50001195);
$id = array(".",".",".",".",".");
$ref = array("T","A","C","C","G");
$alt = array("C","C","T","T","T");

for($i=0; $i<5; $i++)
{
    switch($posi[$i])
    {
        case (($posi[$i] >= 0 ) && ($posi[$i] < 5000000 )):
        $file = "data/ncbi/5.vcf";
        break;

        case (($posi[$i] >= 5000000 ) && ($posi[$i] < 10000000 )):
        $file = "data/ncbi/10.vcf";
        break;

        case (($posi[$i] >= 10000000 ) && ($posi[$i] < 20000000 )):
        $file = "data/ncbi/20.vcf";
        break;

        case (($posi[$i] >= 20000000 ) && ($posi[$i] < 30000000 )):
        $file = "data/ncbi/30.vcf";
        break;

        case (($posi[$i][2] >= 30000000 ) && ($posi[$i] < 40000000 )):
        $file = "data/ncbi/40.vcf";
        break;

        case (($posi[$i] >= 40000000 ) && ($posi[$i] < 50000000 )):
        $file = "data/ncbi/50.vcf";
        break;

        case ($posi[$i] >= 50000000 ):
        $file = "data/ncbi/60.vcf";
        break;
    }

    $handle = fopen($file, "r");

    if ($handle) {
        while (($line = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) {
            $line = explode("\t", $line);
            if($line[1] == $posi[$i] && $line[3] == $ref[$i] && $line[4] == $alt[$i]) {
                echo '<pre>';
                print_r($posi[$i]. "\n");
                print_r($id[$i]. "\n");
                print_r($ref[$i]. "\n");
                print_r($alt[$i]. "\n");
                echo '</pre>';
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!feof($handle)) {
            echo "Error: unexpected fgets() fail\n";
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }        
}
```